# Is there a technique on how to remove aluminum soffit without damaging it?

Tags: exterior, soffit

I Need to remove some existing  sofit so I can  get access to install an electrical outlet  for a motorized awning  . The sofit is 18 inches wide .
Is there a  technique  or  tool that  will allow me to remove this without damaging  it ?

Comment: Cant we see what kind of aluminum soffit you have?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have metal fascia as well, gently remove the nails securing a section of it where you need to work. Flex it out, then remove the hidden nails holding the soffit. Lower the soffit panels slightly by tilting them downward, and slide them past the fascia individually.

Reinstallation is the reverse.